# Error when I run on web and not mobile: the following ProgressEvent$ object was thrown resolving an image codec

Tags: firebase, dart, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I want to call from a Firebase storage to display multiple different images for different purposes. I was expecting a successful call on the different image URLs on the website, but it only works for mobile.

code:

```
 List<Widget> matchItems = [];
 for (int index = 0; index < selectedmatches.length; index++) {
  final matchedUserDoc = selectedmatches[index];
  final matchedUserData = matchedUserDoc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
  final userName = matchedUserData['userName'] ?? '';
  final mission = matchedUserData['mission'] ?? '';
  final active = matchedUserData['active'] ?? '';
  final based = matchedUserData['based'] ?? '';
  final gallery = matchedUserData['gallery'] ?? [];
  final profession = matchedUserData['profression'] ?? [];
  String docname = matchedUserDoc.id;

   if (matchedUserDoc.id == currentUserId) {
    continue;
   }

    matchItems.add(
    Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 16),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
            blurRadius: 6,
            offset: Offset(0, 3),
          ),
        ],
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
      ),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topRight,
            child: Text(
              '$profession',
              style: GoogleFonts.merriweather(
                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 109, 133, 23),
                fontSize: 10,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
              ),
            ),
           ),
          ListTile(
            onTap: () {
              _showUserInfoDialog(
                  matchedUserData, matchedUserDoc.id, index);
            },
            leading: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage: NetworkImage(matchedUserData['profile_pic']),
            ),
            title: Row(
              children: [
                Text(
                  matchedUserData['userName'],
                  style: GoogleFonts.merriweather(
                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 109, 133, 23),
                    fontSize: 18,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 15),
              ],
            ),
            subtitle: Text(
              'matched based on similarities',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.grey,
                fontSize: 14,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 12),
          Text(
            'Mission: $mission',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 14,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 4),
          Text(
            'Active: $active',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 14,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 4),
          Text(
            'Based: $based',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 14,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 8),
          Text(
            'Gallery:',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 14,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 8),
          gallery.isNotEmpty
              ? SizedBox(
                  height: 100,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    itemCount: gallery.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      final imageUrl = gallery[index];
                      return Container(
                        width: 80,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8),
                        child: ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                          child: Image.network(
                            imageUrl,
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                )
              : Text('No images available'),
         ],
       ),
      ),
    );
   }

 if (matchItems.isEmpty) {
  return Container(
    child: Center(
      child: Text('No matches, try to filter your matches'),
    ),
  );
 }`
```

This code is mostly for a main function where it displays a users information. Everything works on mobile, but when I run my code through a website emulator this error is present and doesn't display the profile pic. This happens anytime I call an image from Firebase:

> ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════ The following ProgressEvent$ object was thrown resolving an image codec: [object ProgressEvent] When the exception was thrown, this was the stack Image provider: NetworkImage("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/samaritan-573fc.appspot.com/o/images.jpeg?alt=media&token=92d7a96e-5 363-444a-be1c-5fb4dd217272", scale: 1) Image key: NetworkImage("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/samaritan-573fc.appspot.com/o/images.jpeg?alt=media&token=92d7a96e-5 363-444a-be1c-5fb4dd217272", scale: 1) ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════